# How do I pull the value of something from an SQL database [PHP]?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column in my database called "Admin" that I want to be able to check the value of (whether it's 1 or NULL). And if it's 1 I want it to do something.

How do I write up the query and validate that the entry is = to 1?

Right now I just have the following set up

```
<?php
    include 'db_connect.php';

    if ($_SESSION['username'] == "admin")
    {
        echo '<a href="watWk8.php"> Admin Panel </a>';
        echo '';
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Please log in as admin (user: admin password: admin) to use the admin control panel";
    }
?>
```

Meaning if the user name is admin it will continue running the loop but I want any user to be able to tick a box on registering and have administrative rights. (I know this is destructive but it's just for a school project and a proof of concept)

Thanks!

EDIT:

I tried the following

```html
<?php 
include 'db_connect.php';
$query = "SELECT * from member WHERE Admin = '1'"; 
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query); 
if ($_SESSION['username'] == "admin") 
{ 
    echo '<a href="watWk8.php"> Admin Panel </a>'; 
    echo '';
    echo $result; 
}
 else 
{ 
    echo "Please log in as admin (user: admin password: admin) to use the 
    admin control panel"; } ?>
```

And got the following error after trying to echo it 
[image: https://i.imgur.com/4cBzHog.png]

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-where-clause.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to know about the return type of **`mysqli_query();`** which return a ***mixed type*** variable means it could be an array or binary (True or False) sometimes depends on the query type. The following result may be output as false for error or `array` for data return so use condition for checking the $result simply by:

```
if($result) // or if(count($result) > 0 && $result)
```

If data exists then use a loop for per row data as per your need and for print complete `$result` you need to use a `var_dump()` or `printr()` instead of `echo` like :

```
 var_dump($result);
```

**For details about mysqli_query() follow this link: *http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php***

Answer (score 0):

u are trying something like this maybe..

```
function admin_check( $email, $password ){
    $db = connect();
    if( $db ){
        $admin=1;
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email and password = :password and admin =:admin ");
        $stmt->bindParam(":email", $email);
        $stmt->bindParam(":password", $password);
        $stmt->bindParam(":admin", $admin);
        $stmt->execute();
        $row = $stmt->fetchAll();
        $resultCount = count($row);
        return $resultCount;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, for the right way to connect and get data from DataBase read this manual: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

In the most cases using PDO over mysql or mysqli drivers are much more useful.